# undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/posts/7/up-vote":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/posts/7/up-vote":String:
```

This is my code:

```
<% if policy(Vote.new).create? %>
    <div class="vote-arrows pull-left">
    <div if vote = current_user.vote(post) %>
        <%= link_to [post, Vote.new], post_up_vote_path(post), class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :up_vote do %>
            <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up #{(current_user.voted(post) && current_user.voted(post).up_vote?) ? 'voted' : '' }" ></i>&nbsp; Upvote
            <strong><%= post.points %></strong>
        <% end %>

    <% else %>
        <%= link_to [post, vote], post_down_vote_path(post), class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :down_vote do %> <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down #{(current_user.voted(post) && current_user.voted(post).down_vote?) ? 'voted' : '' }"></i>;nbsp; Downvote
    <% end %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

I am getting the error on this line:

```
<%= link_to [post, Vote.new], post_up_vote_path(post), class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :up_vote do %>
            <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up #{(current_user.voted(post) && current_user.voted(post).up_vote?) ? 'voted' : '' }" ></i>&nbsp; Upvote
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Hm, `link_to` should accept label as its first parameter, no? Why the array there?

Comment: wrong `method` in `link_to` `method: :up_vote` or `method: :down_vote`. Can be only one method - `GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS, HEAD ....`

Comment: yeah, that too. But it's not the main problem.

Comment: Rails ignore this, but OP should know about this.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by `link_to should accept label as its first parameter`...I am new to ruby

Comment: [`List of HTTP methods`](https://annevankesteren.nl/2007/10/http-methods)

Comment: @LouisMorin, meaning it should be something like `link_to 'Downvote', post_down_vote_path(post)` instead of what you have there (the array).

Answer (score 3):

Try going through the code you've posted line-by-line and look for errors. Here's some to check for:

```
  <!-- Mixing HTML and Ruby on this line -->
  <div if vote = current_user.vote(post) %>
```

The `link_to` links need some love. Read the docs carefully and note in particular:

- Valid HTTP verb values for `:method`
- The path only needs to be specified once

`link_to` docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

You may want to spend some time getting the indentation right for the `if/else/ends` as this will make it easier for you to spot syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

The format of a `link_to` call is:

```
link_to "The text in the link", the_path, hash_of_options
```

That the first argument must be text is what Sergio meant by "link_to must accept label as its first parameter". So, something like:

```
<%= link_to "Up-vote the post" , post_up_vote_path(post), class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :up_vote do %>
```

You're giving it a path (or an array that could be converted to a path) as both main arguments.

Check out the docs for the method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Note that your link contains an icon, which should probably take the place of the "label", so your label could just be an empty string.

Comment: Please do not use quote formatting for what isn't a quote.

Comment: Sorry about that, Sergio. I was quoting from memory. Didn't mean to misquote you.